# Add sudo user in boot2docker?

Tags: linux

There is **no sudo group**.
`adduser username` is what I've used to add a user, but he is not a sudoer.

usermod **does not exist**.

I **cannot manage packages as root**.

I **am** logged in as root.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32646952/96588)

Comment: Can anyone try to buck shot a method for adding a sudoer? The sudo group doesn't even exist. I just need a sudoer, then everything will be easy because I'll be able to add packages.